# Passing an array as an unlimited polymorphic object in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, polymorphism

The purpose of my code is to get an array of any type, and do type-specific things to different type. I am using pgfortran (Fortran 03 standard) to compile this and it compiles fine.

However the select type construct in my subroutine "test_class" won't work. It goes to `class default` (which means it's neither integer nor real) every time while my array is actually integer.

What's wrong in my code? Do I need to use pointers?

```
subroutine test_class(array)
  implicit none
  class(*)::array(:)
  select type (array)
  type is (integer)
    print*, 'type is integer'
  type is (real)
    print*, 'type is real'
  class default
    print*, 'no type found'
  end select
end subroutine

program testpoly
  implicit None
  integer::test(3,3),i,j
  do i = 1, 3
    do j = 1, 3
      test(i,j) = i+j
    enddo
  enddo
  call test_class(test)

end program
```

Comment: Note that in addition to requiring an explicit interface, the code also has a rank mismatch between actual and dummy arguments.